# Passing rails variables to javascript lightbox popup

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, magnific-popup

I would need to pass rails variables related to a certain clicked image into its lightbox container.

I'm outputting all of the media uploads into my _content.html.erb layout like this

```
<% @media_uploads.each do |media_upload| %>
<%= media_upload.title %>
<%= media_upload.user.username unless media_upload.user.nil? %>
<%= media_upload.description %>
```

And I'm initializing magnific popup from my application.js when any image is clicked like this

```
$('.box p a').magnificPopup({
  type:'image',
  image: {
    markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+'<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
    '<div class="mfp-box-top">//username, title?</div>'+
    '<div class="mfp-img">//this is where the picture is rendered</div>'+
    '<div class="mfp-box-bottom">//description?</div>'+
    '</div>'+'</div>', 
  }
});
```

Any ideas how to pass the variables from rails to magnific markup? I would like to have appropriate user, title and description (among other things) displayed inside the corresponding popup - inside mfp-box-top and mfp-box-bottom divs.

Thank you for any tips or tricks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve this on the client. The easiest way would be to just render this information additionally as 'data-' attributes on the link or some other html element like this:

```
 <a href='nice.img' data-title='nice', data-user-name='chuck', data-descrption='lorem impsum' />
```

Then query for this info in generic way within the maginific initialiser.

```
    $('.box p a').magnificPopup({
    type:'image',
    image: {
      markup: ...
      '<div class="mfp-box-top">' + $(this).attr('data-title') + '</div>'
      ...
      }
    });
```

Comment: Yup, it does work, but kind of complicates the whole idea I wanted to do if this is the only way of passing vars :/ I would actually like to include into the lightbox, below the picture, several positive/neutral/negative reactions to it which can be voted up on by each user, so not really sure how that would work out. But thanks!